# jquery remove not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove some li lines of html.

This is the html:

[image: HTML]

This is the jquery I'm trying to use:

```
$("li").remove(":contains('undefined')");
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the code you tried work? not work? remove too many? It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("li span:contains('undefined')").remove();
```

It works in my head :)

---

**EDIT** This will remove the LI:

```
$("li span:contains('undefined')").parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: this will remove the `span`, not the `li`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work for me: $("li span:contains('undefined')").parent().parent().remove();

Comment: It worked in jsfiddle - not sure why it's not working in my Rails app.  But thanks, I'll work on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
$("li:contains('undefined')").remove();
```

Comment: I'm curious why this would work when `$("li").remove(":contains('undefined')");` wouldn't.  From what I can tell, it *looks* valid

Comment: Weird indeed, however both this and `$("li").remove(":contains('undefined')");` actually work for me...

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way :

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('span').text().indexOf('undefined') != -1;
}).remove();
```